# How to setup react redux-cookies-middleware?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to setup this middleware [redux-cookies-middleware](https://github.com/grofers/redux-cookies-middleware) 
And I've got this error

> The previous state received by the reducer has unexpected type of
>   "Function". Expected argument to be an object with the following keys:
>   "login"...

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reduxCookiesMiddleware from 'redux-cookies-middleware';
import getStateFromCookies from 'redux-cookies-middleware';

export default function configureStore(initialState={}) {

    // state to persist in cookies
    const paths = {
        'login.token': { name: 'this_token' },
    };

  // Create the store with two middlewares
  const middlewares = [
    thunk,
    reduxCookiesMiddleware(paths),
  ];

  let enhancers;
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') enhancers = [applyMiddleware(...middlewares)];
  else {
    enhancers = [
      applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
    ];
  }


  // read stored data in cookies and merge it with the initial state
    initialState = getStateFromCookies(initialState, paths);

  const store = createStore(
    reducers
    , initialState
    , compose(...enhancers),
  );

  // Extensions
  store.asyncReducers = {}; // Async reducer registry

  return store;
}
```

As I understand the Error is going from // read stored data in cookies and merge it with the initial state. The getStateFromCookies returns a function and merge it to the initialState

> ƒ (store) { return function (next) { return function (action) { var
>   prevState = store.getState(); var result = next(action); var next…

Comment: have you tried with a non empty initialState?

Comment: @ReiDien I use the empty object like a default value. I let the reducers handle initial state and it's not empty

Comment: just try setting your a non empty state. have you investigated the getStateFromCookies? that might give error on empty object

Comment: @ReiDien no luck. I accomplished this by my own way and jsCookies.